# Django culmulative sum of HyperLogLog (HLL) Postgres field

Tags: django, postgresql, hyperloglog

I'm using the [HyperLogLog](https://github.com/citusdata/postgresql-hll) (hll) field to represent unique users, using the Django [`django-pg-hll`](https://pypi.org/project/django-pg-hll/) package. What I'd like to do is get a cumulative total of unique users over a specific time period, but I'm having trouble doing this.

Given a model like:

```
class DailyUsers(model.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  users = HllField()
```

I can get the cummulative `HllField` for each day like so:

```
queryset = models.DailyUsers.objects.annotate(
  cumulative_hll_users=Window(
    UnionAgg("users"), order_by=F('date').asc()
  )
)
```

However, when I try and get the `cardinality` (the actual number) like so:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
  cumsum=Cardinality("cumulative_hll_users")
)
```

The following error occurs:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: OVER specified, but hll_cardinality is not a window function nor an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "app_dailyusers"."date", hll_cardinality...
```

Which is odd because `Cardinality` is defined as an [aggregate](https://github.com/M1hacka/django-pg-hll/blob/master/src/django_pg_hll/aggregate.py#L6) function. I'm not sure if there's a way around this, I imagine it might be possible to do this in raw sql, but I haven't made much progress.

A solution in either the Django ORM or raw SQL would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug occurs because the `django-pg-hll` pacakage uses the `hll_cardinality`function instead of the `#` operator for window functions. Moving to a `raw` sql solution fixed the issue.